# Excel: Increment of one row reference from an Index

Tags: excel, increment, offset

We have multiple worksheets for each room in a construction project that all have cells for perimeter and area, in the same position.

The perimeter and the area are listed in an index under letter C and D; so each room has its perimeter and area listed as an incremental figure (C1;D1-C2;D2-C3-D3 and so on).

Since the cells that represent perimeter and area are in the same place in each sheet, is there a way to reference the cells in each sheet from the index?

We tried offset, but couldn't get to increment to the next sheet.
Any help is appreciated thank you very much.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of the data?

Comment: ..and can show your code?